# Server Objects not available in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, odbc, azure-sql-database, ssms

I spun up an Azure SQL Database and connected to it using SSMS in hopes of following this [tutorial](http://qunect.com/appnotes/uiLinkedServer.html). When I look in Object Explorer, the only two folders I see are "Databases" and "Security"; there is no "Server Objects", and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why not.

[Available Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIhYn.png)

Is it an Azure SQL Database thing? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure SQL Database only allows database access. Server Objects is something you need access to the entire instance/server. If you want to use Azure, you'll need to spin up a VM and install SQL Server on there in order to follow this tutorial.

From the pictures in the tutorial it looks like they have SQL Server Express running on their local machine. If you can, try that route as it'll probably be cheaper and less hassle.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to Azure and setting up SQL Server, in general. I was wondering if it had something to do with it being a "hosted" SQL Server. I appreciate your help!